# Jetpack compose AnimatedVisibility how to trigger enter animation by code?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My code is as follows,how to trigger the enter animation of AnimatedVisibility by code outsie ContentList?

```
    @Composable
    fun ContentList() {
        if (list.size > 0) {
            Box() {
                Column {
                    LazyColumn {
                        items()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Emplty()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Emplty() {
        var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            visible = true
        }
        Box() {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = visible,
                enter = scaleIn() + expandVertically(expandFrom = Alignment.Top),
            ) {
                Image()
            }
        }
    }
```

I want trigger enter animation even though list.size=0.

When list.size=0, the entry animation also needs to be triggered to prompt the user that the list is empty.

Comment: you want your image in emplty to be animated if the list.size = 0?

Comment: Yes，Is there any solution？